# Hotswapping / Edit and continue for C/C++, Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, hotswap, edit-and-continue

I'm looking for an IDE that supports a (Visual Studio's) Edit and continue -like feature. I know Netbeans has it for Java (called hotswapping, Fix and continue), but can not find anything about an implementation for C/C++ for Linux systems.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this feature is not available in the GCC toolchain. The closest you'll get is the gdb's rewind, but that's not the same.